# How do I read the memory at a register offset using gdb

Tags: linux, gdb

I am trying to read the memory at a particular address using GDB and I can't see to find the command to do so.

I need to read the memory at 0x4(%ebp) and 0x8(%ebp). I believe this is possible and should be reasonably easy but every cheat sheet I have looked at so far has not had the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register values can be accessed with the `$reg` syntax. Then the contents at the address in the register and any offset can be examined with `x`.

Example:

```
(gdb) p $rbp
$3 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe0b0
(gdb) p $rbp+4
$4 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe0b4
(gdb) x $rbp+4
0x7fffffffe0b4: 0x00005555
(gdb) x $rbp+8
0x7fffffffe0b8: 0xf7a03bf7
```